# Confusion about holomorphic differential on elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, differential-forms

Let $(a:b)\in\mathbb{C}P^1$ and look at the elliptic curve $C$ given by $y^2=x^3+a^4x+b^6$. It is well known that on this elliptic curve we have the holomorphic differential $dx/y$. I have two questions about this:

- I actually don't understand very well why $dx/y$ is a holomorphic differential. What happens when $y=0$? If you have a reference where this is explained well, that would be also nice.
- I also wanted to know how does this differential actually change when we use another representative of $(a:b)$, say $(\lambda a:\lambda b)$? We can outside $y=0$ write $\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3+a^4x+b^6}}$ and this changes to $\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3+\lambda^4a^4x+\lambda^6b^6}}$. Or does $dx$ itself also change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at a neighbourhood of a point $(t,0)$, and you project it on the $x$-axis, you see that the projection is $2$-to-$1$.

This means that $(x-t)$ is not a uniformizer for the local ring at that point. The projection map $x : E \to \Bbb P^1(k)$ locally looks just like the map $z \mapsto z^2$ around $0$ (if you work over $\Bbb C$ there are actual charts that give this). So, just like $d(z^2) = 2zdz$ has a single zero, $dx$ has order $1$ at that point.

Meanwhile, if you project that neighbourhood on the $y$-axis, it is then $1$-$1$, and so $y$ is a uniformizer for the local ring, and $dy$ has neither a zero nor a pole. This also means that to get the order of a differential $\omega$ you can just write $\omega = f dy$ and look at the order of the rational function $f$.

Indeed, $dx/y = -2/(3x^2+a^4).dy$, and $-2/(3x^2+a^4)$ has order $0$ at $(t,0)$, so $dx/y$ has order $0$.

Next you need to check that $dx/y$ is holomorphic at the point at infinity.

There is only one point at infinity, where $x$ has a pole of order $2$ (so the projection on $\Bbb P^1(k)$ is $2$-to-$1$ around that point and looks just like $1/z^2$ around $0$, and so $dx$ has a pole of order $3$) and $y$ has a pole of order $3$ (and so $dy$ has a pole of order $4$)

So $dx/y$ has order $-3-(-3) = 0$, and so $dx/y$ is holomorphic everywhere.

---

When you change the representative, you also have to rescale $x$ and $y$ by some powers of $\lambda$. (you should give different variable names to $x$ and $y$ and write down the actual isomorphism between the two curves or else you will get confused). Then $dx/y$ will also get rescaled by a power of $\lambda$, so nothing much happens.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one more question: what is actuallu the isomorphism between the elliptic curves $y^2=x^3+a^4x+b^6$ and $y^2=x^3+\lambda^4a^4x+\lambda^6b^6$? I remember my professor mention that they are isomorphic but not the actual isomorphism and I couldnt find it through google either.

Comment: given a point $(x,y)$ on the curve $y^2 = x^3+a^4x+b^6$, you get a point $(x'=\lambda^2 x, y' = \lambda^3 y)$ on the curve $y'^2 = x'^3 + \lambda^4a^4x' + \lambda^6b^6$. When you pullback the differential $dx'/y'$ from the second curve you obtain the differential $d(\lambda^2x)/(\lambda^3y) = \lambda^{-1}(dx/y)$ on the first curve, which is a scalar multiple of $dx/y$.