# Why does the embedding of an elliptic curve in $\Bbb{CP}^2$ look like a torus?

Tags: elliptic-curves

Consider a general elliptic curve of the form $y^2=x^3+ax+b$, where $a,b\in\Bbb{C}$. [These set of notes](https://www.math.uni-tuebingen.de/user/jora/downloads/main.pdf) say that embedding this curve in $\Bbb{CP}^2$ make the zero set look like a torus. I am looking for an explanation of this. Thanks!

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#Elliptic_curves_over_the_complex_numbers) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1735291/276986)

Comment: In the first chapter of Kendig's *Elementary Algebraic Geometry* (Springer GTM Series #44) there are plenty of pictures and explanations that allow you to "see" this (without understanding the parametrization using Weierstrass $\wp$-function and its derivative).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Torus and Elliptic curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2369264/torus-and-elliptic-curves)